# QUERY function to return records with multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a dataset on Google Sheets similar to below:

| Name | Team | Account | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jennifer | East | Meta | 5/1/2023 |
| Steve | East | Alphabet | 4/1/2023 |
| Claire | West | Google | 4/23/2023 |
| Roger | West | Apple | 6/23/2023 |
| Bob | West | Walmart | 5/12/2023 |

I am trying to use the `query()` function to return columns Name, Account and Date where Team equals one of the values listed in cell A1 in the format `West, East`.

Additionally, the value in Date column should be between the date in cell A2 (beginning, inclusive) and cell A3 (ending, inclusive.)

The results should be sorted ascending by date.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the formulas you have tried and what didn't work for you.  Also, include a sample of the output you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `matches` keyword together with a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html), like this:

```
=query( 
  Sheet1!A1:D, 
  "select A, C, D 
   where B matches '" & join("|", split(A1, ", ", false, true)) & "' 
   and date " & text(A2, "'yyyy-MM-dd'") & " <= toDate(D) 
   and toDate(D) <= date " & text(A2, "'yyyy-MM-dd'") & " 
   order by D asc", 
  1 
)
```